# How to insert data using MongoDB and PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

While I'm trying to run the following script, it has shown the error message.

**Collection selected succsessfully
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function insert() on null in /var/www/html/checkmongoDB.php:27 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/checkmongoDB.php on line 27**

Help me to fix that issue.

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);  

   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");;


   $db = $m->kevellclub;

   $collection = $db->users;
   echo "Collection selected succsessfully";
   $document = array(
            "firstname" => "my firstname",
            "lastname" =>"my lastname",
            "email_id" => "my email id",
            "password" => "my password",
            "addressline1" => "addressline One",
            "addressline2" => "address Line 2",
            "city" => "Cityname",
            "state" => "my state",
            "country" => "my country",
            "pincode" => "my pincode"
    );

 if($collection->insert($document))
{
    echo "Collection Created !";
}
?>
```

Comment: Please add the code as actual code, not as an image. It seems that the `$db->users` returns null which could mean that there are no users, check your database if there are any.

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin, thanks for your response, I had created a collection in the name of users in my database (kevellclub). I tried to insert into users using PHP MongoDB, but can't able to do.